# No existe un elemento tomado por querySelector

Tags: javascript, html5

Cuando ejecuto el siguiente codigo, no llama a textContent porque me indica que 'miTitulo' no existe.

```js
var miTitulo=document.querySelector("h1");
var miBoton=document.querySelector("button");
console.log(miTitulo);
function Bienvenida() {
 var miNombre= prompt('ingrese su nombre');
 localStorage.setItem('nombre', miNombre);
 miTitulo.textContent='Bienvenido '+miNombre;
}
window.addEventListener('load',Bienvenida,false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="PruebaEditable.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background: gray">
 <h1>Bienvenido a mi pagina, </h1>
 <button>Cambiar usuario</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que estás suministrando un parametro inexistente al `.queryselector()`. Lo recomendable es que apuntes siempre al id o clase del elemento cuando utilices `queryselector()`.

Tu código funciona si por ejemplo agregamos `id` a cada elemento ***HTML*** y lo usamos de referencia para **miTitulo** y **miBoton**. Así:

```js
var miTitulo=document.querySelector("#titulo");
var miBoton=document.querySelector("#cambiar");
console.log(miTitulo);
function Bienvenida() {
 var miNombre= prompt('ingrese su nombre');
 localStorage.setItem('nombre', miNombre);
 miTitulo.textContent='Bienvenido '+miNombre;
}
window.addEventListener('load',Bienvenida,false);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <script src="PruebaEditable.js"></script>
</head>
<body style="background: gray">
 <h1 id="titulo">Bienvenido a mi pagina, </h1>
 <button "cambiar">Cambiar usuario</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Puedes revisar para más información: [ejemplos válidos de parametros usados en queryselector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector)

Espero sea de ayuda. Un saludo!